# How do you detect DOCTYPE (Transitional or Strict) server-side in ASP.NET?

Tags: c#, asp.net, doctype, xhtml-1.0-strict, xhtml-transitional

I am wondering if there is a way to detect from the server-side which DOCTYPE the page is specified as. I have some HTML and CSS in a custom WebControl that renders differently depending on which DOCTYPE the page is. Is there a `Page` property or a `Response` property I could check?

Comment: What do you need to render differently depending on the doctype...?

Comment: i was creating rounded corners using a div with margin-left/right. in DOCTYPE Traditional the margin wasn't working like it was in an HTML file with no DOCTYPE specified.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you have an enum or a boolean on your control that the consuming pages can set (it's not like the doctype should be changing from page to page)?

Comment: i'm taking our old TABLE-based container control and changing it to a less-markup (and better) DIV-based container, ideally making it function and display same as it did before the change. But I can't guarantee all of the pages in all our apps have DOCTYPE set to Transitional

Comment: Why don't you do as I suggested then? Have each page individually set a variable?

Comment: We have a lot of apps with a lot of pages. The ideal solution would be to have a custom WebControl that can adapt itself instead of having developers be responsibly for managing a variable.

Comment: Ok, then why don't you create two seperate controls? The *ideal* solution would be to take the time to copy-paste the proper doctype when you add the control obviously...

Comment: The thing is, this control is already in use. but when people move forward to a newer WebControls DLL, the markup for the control will be different.

Answer (score 0):

Thing is, DOCTYPE is a client side declaration and it doesn't take part the control structure of ASP.NET pages (because it exists outside the `html` element of the page).  I concur with @TheCloudlessSky, pass the setting to the control, as the only way I can see you detecting DOCTYPE is by opening up the file itself and reading the first line, this is also pretty useless for compiled web applications too.

Why will the DOCTYPE be changing from page to page?

Comment: Ideally, all pages in all of our apps would have the same Visual Studio DOCTYPE, but I don't want to just assume that. I can also see other developers possibly changing it. Why? I don't know. Devs do funny things sometimes. ;)

Comment: To be honest, you're probably best just making your user control produce consistent semantic markup, based on XHTML.  It's not going to harm any renders which use say, HTML4, XHTML1.0, XHTML1.1 or HTML5.

Answer (score 0):

The DocType will not change from page to page, but you do sometimes need access to it. I am scouring the internet at the moment trying to get at this data.

I know it is there in first HTMLElement (DomElement.data) because it is properly listed in debug mode, but using something like -

dElementList[str].DomElement.data;

This seems to be the only place where the data I need to get at exists, the data inside

Is not posible. I suspect there is a cast needed to a specific element type, but I have not yet come across it. The MSDN example for DomElement does not access any of the elements, but their code is basically the same as mine, dElement is a Dictionary, str is the ID or tag of the element (in this case '!' from it's tag), the Dictionary returns a HTMLElement.

So does anyone know how we get at the at DomElement.data ?