# Determining doctype of current page or master page programmatically

Tags: asp.net, doctype

I need to be able to programmatically determine the doctype of the current page (.aspx), whether its set directly within the page itself, or via a master page.

The reason is so I can output correctly formatted html from custom controls or components based on whether the doctype is plain html, xhtml, xml or whatever.

Comment: May be duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3247513/how-do-you-detect-doctype-transitional-or-strict-server-side-in-asp-net

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a literal tag for your doctype declarations and control it in code behind.

Answer (score 0):

I can't think of a way to reliably do what you want to do. You could obviously manually parse the master page but that wouldn't handle the dynamic case. I would recommend adding an attribute to your control that specifies the rendering mode and force your consumers to set it (default to XHTML probably since that's the VS default).